# Can I use MPI_Probe to probe messages sent by a collective operation?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

In my code I have a server process repeatedly probing for incoming messages, which come in two types.
One type of the two will be sent once by each process to give hint to the server process about its
termination.

I was wondering if it is valid to use MPI_Broadcast to broadcast these termination messages and use MPI_Probe to probe their arrivals.

I tried using this combination but it failed. This failure might have been caused by some other things. So I would like anyone who knows about this to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can only use MPI_Probe for testing for point-to-point communications.   For collective communications, the only way to participate at all is to actively make the collective call.  From the definition of [MPI_Probe in the standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node50.html), "The call matches the same message that would have been received by a call to MPI_RECV(..., source, tag, comm, status) executed at the same point in the program" -- eg, it only matches point-to-point stuff like Recv would.

With the new nonblocking collectives coming in MPI3, you would however be able to use MPI_Test (or MPI_Wait) to check to see the status of the nonblocking request, just as you would with a nonblocking send/recv, although I haven't been following that WGs work too closely so I don't know the details.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent clarification again as always.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the MPI standard excludes this, but I don't see how it would be useful if it is possible.  On the (rare) occasions when I've used `mpi_probe` I've used it to find out the size of an incoming message; it can, of course, get other information about messages 'in flight' too.  But `mpi_bcast` is a collective operation so all the processes in a communicator know everything about a message that you could use `mpi_probe` to find out.  I think ?

Comment: many thanks for your answer.
The reason why I attempted the seemingly foolish combination is that MPI_BCast is always claimed by many books to outperform the case where each processor individually sends a message.